# different Popup on click in ios in different locations on a image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have 5 small circles on a image. I want that when I click anywhere within the circle a popup should come. But this popup will be different for each circle. I have the center cg-point and radius of the circle. How can i do this in Objective c?? thanks in advance

Comment: How about adding some if-else conditions to determine which circle is tapped?